# How do I set CoreLocation usage description for macOS?

Tags: macos, core-location, info.plist, location-services

I'm trying to set the string that is shown when my app requests location authorization. I've tried setting all [four possible keys in Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW14):

```
NSLocationUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

I've also tried setting the `locationManager.purpose` string [which is deprecated in iOS, but not macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423742-purpose?language=objc). None of these methods cause the string to appear in the alert when the app requests authorization.

I'm using this code to request access:

```
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of the alert:

[image]

Calendar.app is able to customize the alert:

[image]

Comment: Do you see the alert? What message is there?
Do you by chance loose the reference to the locationManager?

Comment: Yes, the alert shows up as expected. Just without the usage description string.  It says ““app” would like to access your location.” `locationManager` is set at the class level so I don’t think that’s getting lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct location usage description on macOS appears to be `NSLocationUsageDescription` (Privacy - Location Usage Description). It turns out that I was setting it correctly, but CoreLocation must have been caching the string (or lack thereof).  It might take a day to finally decide to use the new string, since even rebooting doesn't seem to change anything. You should be able to test the new string by changing the app's bundle identifier to get around the caching.

Comment: I asked Apple DTS about this. They suggested you can get around the caching by the terminal command

tccutil reset CoreLocationAgent

and then restarting the computer